# MongoAutoConfiguration not working after excluding BatchAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on a spring-boot batch application which was working fine when its **parent** (pom.xml) was

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
```

**pom.xml** before change

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>project-artefact</artifactId>
    <name>project-name</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring.batch.test.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.test.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.18</lombok.version>
        <jaxb2.runtime.version>1.11.1</jaxb2.runtime.version>
        <flapdoodle.embed.mongo.version>1.50.5</flapdoodle.embed.mongo.version>
        <embedmongo-spring.version>RELEASE</embedmongo-spring.version>
        <spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spock.version>
        <groovy.version>2.4.12</groovy.version>
        <wiremock.version>2.12.0</wiremock.version>
        <spring.spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spring.spock.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.0</jacoco.version>
        <!-- Test coverage -->
        <jacoco.outputDir>${project.build.directory}</jacoco.outputDir>
        <!-- Unit test report path -->
        <jacoco.out.ut.file>jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.out.ut.file>
        <jacoco.reportPath>${jacoco.outputDir}/${jacoco.out.ut.file}</jacoco.reportPath>

        <!-- Integration test report path-->
        <jacoco.out.it.file>jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.out.it.file>
        <jacoco.itReportPath>${jacoco.outputDir}/${jacoco.out.it.file}</jacoco.itReportPath>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.test.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jongo/jongo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2.runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>${flapdoodle.embed.mongo.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${embedmongo-spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>${wiremock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin,
                visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>some.package</generatePackage>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generateDirectory>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-no-header</arg>
                                <arg>-Xxew</arg>
                                <arg>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</arg>
                                <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                                <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                                <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                            </args>
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.9.5</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.5</version>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Sets up jacaco for unit test coverage analysis (jacoco.agent.ut.arg) -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-ut-agent</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

However, today I had to change the **parent** in pom.xml to use organisational's default parent being used for all other projects (These projects dont use Spring boot). Now, to overcome this I followed [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent) and added `spring-boot-dependencies` in `<dependencyManagement>` tag of pom.xml.

New **pom.xml** after change:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>project-artefact</artifactId>
    <name>project-name</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../relative-path</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring.batch.test.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.test.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.18</lombok.version>
        <jaxb2.runtime.version>1.11.1</jaxb2.runtime.version>
        <flapdoodle.embed.mongo.version>1.50.5</flapdoodle.embed.mongo.version>
        <embedmongo-spring.version>RELEASE</embedmongo-spring.version>
        <spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spock.version>
        <groovy.version>2.4.12</groovy.version>
        <wiremock.version>2.12.0</wiremock.version>
        <spring.spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spring.spock.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.0</jacoco.version>
        <!-- Test coverage -->
        <jacoco.outputDir>${project.build.directory}</jacoco.outputDir>
        <!-- Unit test report path -->
        <jacoco.out.ut.file>jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.out.ut.file>
        <jacoco.reportPath>${jacoco.outputDir}/${jacoco.out.ut.file}</jacoco.reportPath>

        <!-- Integration test report path-->
        <jacoco.out.it.file>jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.out.it.file>
        <jacoco.itReportPath>${jacoco.outputDir}/${jacoco.out.it.file}</jacoco.itReportPath>
        <datamining.common.version>2017.12-SNAPSHOT</datamining.common.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2.runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>${flapdoodle.embed.mongo.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${embedmongo-spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.test.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>${wiremock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin,
                visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>some.package</generatePackage>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generateDirectory>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-no-header</arg>
                                <arg>-Xxew</arg>
                                <arg>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</arg>
                                <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                                <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                                <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                            </args>
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.9.5</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.5</version>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Sets up jacaco for unit test coverage analysis (jacoco.agent.ut.arg) -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-ut-agent</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This started giving me following error whenever I use to run the executable artefact jar prepared from `mvn spring-boot:repackage`

```
Parameter 0 of method basicBatchConfigurer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$JpaBatchConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager'
```

This made exclude `BatchAutoConfiguration` from `@SpringBootApplication` autoconfiguration exclusions, like this,

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
```

It makes the application start, but now I see except `spring.data.mongodb.database` in `application.properties`, none of the other mongoDB auto-configuration properties (`spring.data.mongodb.*`) gets picked up!

Could you please help how to resolve it?

Comment: Without seeing your POMs, this is going to be hard to diagnose.  What I'd recommend is to do a `mvn dependency:tree` on the old version and new version and compare the libraries you're pulling in.

Comment: I have added pom.xml for review

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the problem.

The initial problem of suddenly getting `BatchAutoConfiguration$JpaBatchConfiguration` require a `DataSource` was because of a local dependency I added in **new** pom.xml which brought in

```
javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
```

in the classpath. 
This activated `BatchAutoConfiguration.JpaBatchConfiguration` which then needed a `javax.sql.DataSource` bean.

After excluding the dependency of `javax.persistence` the `BatchAutoConfiguration` issue goes away.

Now, `MongoAutoConfiguration` not being picked up, wasn't an issue and I am sorry I didn't dig in well. It was actually being picked up but the reason data wasn't being inserted in my mongoDB was an issue in my code sending no data to write to `org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter`.

I got my lesson (again!!) of not doing too many changes in code at one point of time ;)

Comment: I know this is months late, and you probably lost context of it all, but in the off chance that you do, I'm really struggling with same situation for hours on end with no luck! Looking for guidance, world!